# Undefined index notice when using the $args parameter in add_settings_field()

Tags: php, settings-api

I'm using the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to provide my admin-user with some options for a plugin I'm writing. I have about 30 text fields to output on the plugin options page so I have created a very general callback:

```
public function my_fields_callback( $args ) {

    $name = esc_attr( $args['name'] );
    $value = esc_attr( $args['value'] );
    echo "<input type='text' name='$name' value='$value' />";

}
```

The part I'm having problems with is the `$args` parameter in [add_settings_field()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field). Specifically, I'm getting the following PHP debug notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: height
>
> Notice: Undefined index: weight

Here is how I'm adding my settings field(s):

```
add_settings_field( 'field-1', 'Field One', array( $this, 'my_fields_callback' ), 'slug', 'section', array( 'name' => 'settings[weight]', 'value' => $settings['weight'] ) );

add_settings_field( 'field-2', 'Field Two', array( $this, 'my_fields_callback' ), 'slug', 'section', array( 'name' => 'settings[height]', 'value' => $settings['height'] ) );
```

Why am I getting the 'undefined index' notice and how can I avoid this? I'm trying to pinpoint what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The array `$settings` has no `width` and `height` keys (indexes), which is why you're getting these errors. Where are you defining `$settings`?

Comment: Ah, that might be the problem. I haven't defined `$settings`. Where and how should I define it?